# Quadratic residues that are also squares themselves

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers, quadratic-residues

I have a question about number bases and square numbers. When considering quadratic residues in a given modulus (without eliminating residues that are not relatively prime to the modulus), it is evident that in a number of smaller moduli the squares that are less than the modulus comprise all the quadratic residues that it has, such that there are not any "false squares."
This is the same question as asking whether a square when written in a given number base can only have a square in the one's place. For example, in base ten this is not the case, since a square can end in 0,1,4,5,6,9, and 5 and 6 are not squares. On the other hand, in both the duodecimal and hexadecimal systems a square can only end in 0,1,4,9, all of which are squares in themselves.
For which number bases is this always the case, and is there a standard proof for it?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  The question in the header seems unrelated to the discussion in the body.  And the question about the units place seems unrelated to any modulus.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that you are asking "for which, possibly composite, moduli $m$ is it true that the least positive residues of each quadratic residue $\pmod m$ is actually a square in $\mathbb N$?"  If so, then there can't be many examples.  For prime moduli, $p$, say, there are $\frac {p+1}2$ quadratic residues (counting $0$) and there are only about $\sqrt p$ squares.  Other than for  very small $p$, your property can not hold.  For $p=5$, say, there are three quadratic residues and three natural squares.  That's the last one though.

Comment: @lulu Is there a formula for the number of quadratic residues for composite moduli?

Comment: @eyeballfrog  By CRT you just need to multiply the number of squares $\pmod {p^k}$ for each prime power factor.  Probably an easy count for those...don't see it immediately though.

Comment: @eyeballfrog  Yeah...the relatively prime squares just behave like they do $\pmod p$ since $a^2\equiv b^2 \pmod {p^k}$ means $p^k$ divides one of $a-b, a+b$.  That, I think, should make the count easy enough.

Comment: the bases where this works are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 16,$  and that's it. Next, when a base fails, this occurs with some $x$  just above $\left\lfloor  \sqrt b \right\rfloor. $  The biggest I have so far is $b=96,$  where the first failure is $9 + 3 = 12$   where $144 \equiv 48 \pmod {96}.$     More common is difference 2 or 1,  for example $b=32$  with integer square root $5.$   We see $6^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{32}$  but the very next one $7^2 \equiv 17 \pmod {32}$

Comment: got organized about priniting out the differences ////////// base  48  x: 9  x^2:  81  reduced  33   OH NO 3   //////////    base  720  x: 30  x^2:  900  reduced  180   OH NO 4   ////////////  base  60480  x: 250  x^2:  62500  reduced  2020   OH NO 5  ///////////  with base up to 100000

Answer (score 1):

the observations on small numbers do lead to a proof.
First, the number $d(n)$  of positive divisors of $n$  satisfies $d(n) < 2 \sqrt n,$ simply because  each divisor $u  > \sqrt n$  pairs up with a divisor $\frac{n}{u}  < \sqrt n.$  Even if $n$ itself is a square, you get just one extra....  We may need a stronger one,
$$ d(n) \leq 48 \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{2520}}  $$   with equality only at $n= 2520.$

Now, suppose  $B \geq 17.$ For every number $x$ with $\sqrt B < x < \sqrt{2B}, $   we see $x^2$  lies between $B$ and $2B.$   Furthermore, the reduction $\pmod B$  is then exactly $x^2 - B  .$   How often can this be a square?  If so, we have some $y < \sqrt B$   such that
$$   x^2 - B = y^2  $$   or
$$  x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y) = B   $$
Every time we find such an $x,y$  we have a (disticnt) divisor $(x+y),$   one for each value of $x$ that works out. The count of $x$ values is $\sqrt{2B}  - \sqrt B \approx \frac {\sqrt B}{\sqrt 2 + 1}.$

For large enough $B$  this is much  more than $48 \sqrt[3]{\frac{B}{2520}}  $  and there are $x$ values that do not lead to divisors of $B;$   such an $x$ means failure.

Enough for now.

just numerical illustration, I ran all $B \leq 1000000. $  The bound with the cube root says $d(1000000) < 352.73 \; \; .$  In comparison, $\sqrt{2000000}  - \sqrt{1000000} \approx  414.21 \; \; , $  which is already bigger than the cube root thing.